# Decimal to Binary Number Representation Logical Error

Tags: c, binary, logic

I have been instructed to write a program that will represent a decimal as a 32 bit binary number. My code is working, compiling properly, but the output is not correct. I have used every resource but it seems to be a small error and I can't pick it out.

This is my code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "binary.h"

int exponent;
int rem;
int binary_array[32];
int position;
int x;

int twos_complement(int x){}

void binary(int x, int position, int binary_array[]) {
    exponent = 31;

    for (; exponent >= 0; exponent--) {
        rem = x % (int)pow(2, exponent);
        if (rem == x) {
            binary_array[position] = 0;
            position++; 
        } else if (rem < x) {
            binary_array[position] = 1;
            position++;
            binary(rem, position, binary_array);
        }
    }
}

int main(int x) {
    x = 563;
    position = 0;
    binary(x, position, binary_array);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%d", binary_array[i]); 
    }   
    printf("\n");
}
```

As you can see, I set `x = 563`. But I am getting the output `00000000000000000000001000000000` which is not correct. It is correctly identifying that `563 % 512 = 51` which is less than `563` but it doesn't continue on and makes all the remaining bits `0`. The logic for my `if` statements was an attempt to discern if a number was larger than `x`. Example: 563 / 1024 = 0 R 563. As long as the remainder is equal to the dividend, I reasoned that it was being divided by a number larger than it and that the bit should be 0.

Comment: "My code is working, compiling properly, but the output is not correct." Your code is _not working_. It's merely _compiling without error_. That's a common beginner terminology mistake.

Comment: My advice is to learn to use your debugger. Seriously. If they haven't taught this in your course yet they should. Aside from that, check with your teaching staff or other students for some pair programming help.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `main` would only get 1 integer parameter? And also why do you use an integer parameter for something only relevant within the function? Use a local variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your method does not work. Instead of testing if the remainder is equal to `x`, which will be true for all powers of 2 greater than `x`, you should use the bitwise and operator (`&`) to test if the corresponding bit is set.

I don't understand either why you make `binary` call itself recursively, nor why you make the temporary variables global.

Furthermore, `int main(int x)` is not a valid prototype for the `main` function, and defining `x` this way in `main` hides the global variable with the same name.

Finally `(int)pow(2, exponent)` has undefined behavior for the first iteration as 2<sup>31</sup> is beyond the range of 32-bit signed integers.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void binary(unsigned int x, int binary_array[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if (x & (1U << (31 - i)))
            binary_array[i] = 1;
        else
            binary_array[i] = 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int binary_array[32];

    binary(563, binary_array);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%d", binary_array[i]); 
    }   
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want check is that how many decimals can 32bits represent with binaries accurately. As there is a limit:

There are only certain amount of of bits for them, as there is one for the sign and then 8 bits I think is used by the left side multiplier definition.

That leaves you 23 bits which can present only certain lenght integer as on the right side (the decimal maximum comes from these bits as technical limitation, and they can be only this accurate before rounding kicks in)

See: [how the bits are used for floating point numbers in 32bits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dxrq.jpg)

In order to fix that ^^ remember to round you decimal number to maximum of 5 length as the fraction on the right side. As any decimals more accurate will get goofed, like 0,123456 you would like to round to 0,12346 before trying to fit it to 32bits.

Comment: So the important thing here is to realize that you cannot offer a fraction that exceed what 23 bit can offer, that must be integer of 1-99999, if you over length 5, you’re code will boom or it crops out (rounds ‘wrongly’)…depending how strictly was the 32bits defined into your result variable. Sure if you let it use more bits (64) you can get more accurate fraction, I think was of lenght 15 max. 

The binary you show has its first 1 on the 23th, you might have the reason from these limitations popping by :)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with C23, it is easy.

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned x = 563;
    printf("%u\n", x);   // Print as decimal
    printf("%032b\n", x);// Print as 32 digit binary 
}
```

Otherwise, rather than finding the most significant bit first, start with the least significant bit.

```
void binary(unsigned x, /* int position is not needed, */ int binary_array[]) {
    for (unsigned index = 32; index > 0; ) {
      binary_array[--index] = x % 2;
      x /= 2;
    }
}
```